# Equation Error - Undefined Control Sequence

Tags: equations, align

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{textgreek}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \begin{document} 

    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    \theta_1^*(t) ~ P(\theta_1| Y_1^{obs}, Y_2^{(t-1)},…,Y_p^{(t-1)})\\
Y_1^{*(t)} ~ P(Y_1| Y_1^{obs}, Y_2^{(t-1)},…,Y_p^{(t-1)}, theta_1^{*(t)}) %<----stops here
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}
    \end{document}
```

Hello, I'm trying to input equations into my thesis and I've been trying for quite sometime now, but it always stops at the line indicated in the code. I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Please could someone help me.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) it is always a good idea to cite the error you get. (3) where is `\Y` defined? (4) You'd probably want `\dots` instead of `…` (utf8 char) since the latter is apparently defined as something `\textellipsis` (by inputenc) and as the name suggests this is a text symbol that cannot be used in math mode.

Comment: and  (5) it should be `\theta` not `theta` ...

Comment: (5) what should this mean: `Y_p^(t-1)`? currently it makes `(` into a superscript, perhaps you meant `Y_p^{(t-1)}`? (6) you are missing a ``\`` at the end in `theta`

Comment: (7) you probably also mean `Y_1^{\textyp{obs}}` not `Y_1^obs`

Comment: Hello, I dont know where I typed the edit reference. I cant see it in my edit in the question. But yes, thanks for pointing it out. The \Y was a typ0

Comment: but writing of `theta` is still wrong!

Comment: (8) and  `~` should probably be replaced by `\sim`

Comment: apparently you not. it works at me ...

Comment: \begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\theta_1^*(t) ~ P(\theta_1| Y_1^{obs}, Y_2^{(t-1)}, \dots,Y_p^{(t-1)})\\
Y_1^{*(t)} ~ P(Y_1| Y_1^{obs}, Y_2^{(t-1)},\dots,Y_p^{(t-1)}, \theta_1^{*(t)})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thanks, this works! 
And the ~ as \sim gave me an error, so I used ~ itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. `~` does not produce a visible symbol; you probably want `\sim`
2. `…` should be `\dots`
3. `Y_p^(t-1)` should be `Y_p^{t-1}`;
4. `theta` should be `\theta`
5. `|` should be `\mid` or the spacing would be wrong
6. `^obs` should be `^{\mathrm{obs}}` so the superscript is in textual mode and a single object
7. `\Y` should probably be `Y`
8. you are missing an alignment point

Here is the fixed code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\theta_1^*(t) &\sim P(\theta_1\mid Y_1^{\mathrm{obs}}, Y_2^{t-1},\dots,Y_p^{t-1})\\
Y_1^*(t) &\sim P(Y_1\mid Y_1^{\mathrm{obs}}, Y_2^{t-1},\dots,Y_p^{t-1},\theta_1^*(t))
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted a space instead of a `~` symbol:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Prob}{\mathnormal{P}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&\theta_1^*(t) \Prob(\theta_1\mid Y_1^{\mathrm{obs}}, Y_2^{t-1},\dots,Y_p^{t-1})\\
&Y_1^*(t) \Prob(Y_1\mid Y_1^{\mathrm{obs}}, Y_2^{t-1},\dots,Y_p^{t-1},\theta_1^*(t))
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: all this was said in comments ... but you not consider given advises

Comment: @Zarko Yes, while I was writing my answer. Made CW anyway.

Comment: @egreg, no, your answer is sufficient.

Comment: @Zarko I did, I was incorporating the \theta as the comments were made.

Comment: @Ar1229, than you should obtain the same solution as *egreg* provide !

Comment: @Zarko My last comment under your comment was 16 mins ago, if you check it. And I did say I got it. 
The solution egreg gave is more aligned and more readable than the one I got.